# How can I clone a suscriber profile in wordpress

Tags: users

Just need PHP code or some way to have a clone button under users like we have code for cloning pages & posts.

Comment: When you say you want to clone user, what do you want to clone? because email, login and nicename are unique (if I remember correctly), what do you want to happen in those cases? if you are using plugins, like WooCommerce, they also add meta data to user, do you want to clone them as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the ideal thing to copy users because in WP, email must be unique and there are no drafts or pending user status so WordPress not allow to clone  users with same email id.